# Counting number of possible grade assignments

Tags: combinatorics

Given 100 students who are to be assigned a grade 1 to 5, what is the number of possible assignments if we are interested in knowing what grade each student received. Furthermore, we are given the constraints that at least 30 students receive a grade of 4.

The way I approached this problem was by saying that since in all grade distributions at least 30 students must achieve a grade of 4 then we can "reserve" those using $100\choose 30$. This leaves us with 70 students that can be assigned grades using $5^{70}$. The final result would then be given by
$${100\choose 30}\cdot{5^{70}}$$

However, the actual solution is $$\sum_{k=30}^{100}{100\choose k}{\cdot}{4^{100-k}}$$
which also makes sense to me. I just can't seem to make out how exactly the two constructs differ and what my version is actually representing.

Comment: Your calculation counts some combinations multiple times.  For example, if all of the students receive the grade 4, how many different times does your calculation count them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solution is overcounting situations where more than $30$ people receive a grade of four. In your method, you select $30$ people to receive a grade of four, then assign the remaining grades arbitrarily. These initial $30$ people are given a special treatment they should not have.

**Example:** Consider the following two ways to assign grades according to your formula:

1. - Choose persons $1$ to $30$ to receive a grade of $4$.
   - For everyone else: assign persons $31$ to $40$ a grade of $4$, and persons $41$ to $100$ a grade of $1$.
2. - Choose persons $11$ to $40$ to receive a grade of $4$.
   - For everyone else: assign persons $1$ to $10$ a grade of $4$, and persons $41$ to $100$ a grade of $1$.

Both of these result in the same grade distribution (persons $1$ to $40$ have $4$, persons $41$ to $100$ have $1$), but they are counted as distinct by your formula.

To eliminate this overcounting, you choose all the people who get grades of $4$ at once, and then assign the grades $1,2,3,5$ arbitrarily to the others. There are now only four choices for each other students.

---

Your mistake is a very common pitfall for people learning combinatorics. Learning how to spot this mistake and avoid it in the future is a very important step for becoming good at combinatorics.

Answer (score 1):

let's use smaller numbers for intuition.  Assume two grade levels and 3 students.  Assume again at least one student gets lower grade.  So you have these scenarios

$\{1,2,2\}, \{2,1,2\}, \{2,2,1\}, \{1,1,2\},\{1,2,1\},\{2,1,1\}, \{1,1,1\}$

using your way will give $ {3 \choose 1} 2^2 = 12$, which is clearly wrong.

Using the proposed solution: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{3}{3\choose k}{1^{3-k}}= 3 + 3 + 1 = 7$$